# Alignment of label and textbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing this issue again with the alignment which I am unable to rectify. I don't know what I am missing out. Please find the plunkr [https://plnkr.co/edit/UD0YZQhgOjIoJ1nqg7sb?p=preview] .Please maximise the plunkr output for the actual output I am getting.  Any help people?

Html code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div ng-controller="headerCtrl">
  <div class="container" style="padding-top:20px;">
    <div ng-app="TimeSheet" data-ng-controller="headerCtrl" class="container" style="margin-top:60px">
      <div ng-show="error" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <p>{{ error }}</p>
      </div>
      <!--<p><a data-ng-click="showadd()" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary">Generate Report</a></p>-->
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <section>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="form-horizontal">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-sm-5 control-label">UserID</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <select data-ng-model="user.userid" class="form-control" id="title" required>
                        <option value="" selected="selected">(Select User ID)</option>
                        <option value="user1">user1</option>
                        <option value="user2">user2</option>
                        <option value="user3">user3</option>
                        <option value="user4">user4</option>
                      </select>

                      <!--<input type="text" data-ng-model="user.userid" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter your User ID" required title="Enter your UserID" />-->
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Status</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      Active
                      <input name="Status" type="radio" data-ng-model="user.ResultStatus" value="Active" required title="Choose status">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; In-Active
                      <input name="Status" type="radio" data-ng-model="user.ResultStatus" value="InActive" required title="Choose status">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="startDate" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Date</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <input name="startDate" data-ng-model="user.date" id="startDate" class="date-picker" required />
                      <!--<input type="text" data-ng-model="user.projectid" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter your Project ID" required title="Enter your ProjectID" />-->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
                      <span data-ng-hide="editMode">
                                                    <input type="submit" value="Generate" ng-disabled="adduserform.$invalid" data-ng-click="add()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                                </span>
                      <span data-ng-show="editMode">
                                                    <input type="submit" value="Update" ng-disabled="adduserform.$invalid" data-ng-click="update()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                                </span>
                      <input type="button" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

you can see the alignment issue here in this image below

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal and verifiable example, with the expected output?

Comment: Yeah sure. Let me edit

Comment: What is not working or issue?

Comment: Can you set up fiddle for your problem

Comment: @AbhishekPandey the labels user id, status, date are not aligned properly. You can check that in plunkr expanded output.

Comment: @Learning I tried in fiddle but I am not getting the output I got in my system. So updated the code in plunkr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the date input span the whole width, you need the [`.form-control`](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#form-controls) class on it.

```
<input name="startDate" data-ng-model="user.date" id="startDate" class="form-control date-picker" required />
```

Also note that the `<input>` tag must have a type attribute with it.

You have a container within a container for your timesheet div. Removing the `.container` class from the timesheet div fixes the alignment issue.

Also, put the `<table>` in a row and a column:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <!-- Your table here -->
        <table class="table table-hover">
            ...
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

[See it working here](https://plnkr.co/edit/yYOGJswyaUWP5XFRKfSG?p=preview).

Comment: I checked your working example. userid , status and date labels are not aligned properly

Comment: Do you want to set the date _label_, do you mean that the input box doesn't span the whole width?

Comment: as we can the fields are not aligned properly vertically. Status is lil front, date too